# get values in an array inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question here I want to get all the `value` of the `values` array inside this array.

```js
const sample = [
  {
    "key": "sampleKey", "values":
      [
        { "key": "insidesampleKey", "value": 2 },
        { "key": "insideofinside", "value": 2 }
      ]
  },

  { 
    "key": "sampleKey2", "values": 
      [
        { "key": "insideSampleKey2", "value": 1 }
      ] 
  },

  { 
    "key": "samplkey3", "values": 
      [
        { "key": "insideofsampleKey3", "value": 1 }
      ] 
  }
]
```

So far, I can only print the first one `console.log(sample[0].values[0].value)`. I appreciate with any helps. Thanks much and have a great weekend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)  may be the best way to deal with this.

sample.flatMap(outer => outer.values.map(inner => inner.value))

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` and `concat` to get a flat, single array.

```js
const sample = [{"key":"sampleKey","values":
  [{"key":"insidesampleKey","value":2},{"key":"insideofinside","value":2}]},

{"key":"sampleKey2","values":[{"key":"insideSampleKey2","value":1}]},

{"key":"samplkey3","values":[{"key":"insideofsampleKey3","value":1}]}]

var values = sample.reduce((acc, item) => acc.concat(item.values.map(v=> v.value)),[]);
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to use a flatMap over the array as below. You can use polyfill for browsers that don't support the same yet. Use MDN to learn more.

```
sample.flatMap(item => item.values.map(inner => inner.value))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the other `value` properties, just `map` over the array, then look at the `values` array, then look at `value`, and finally use `flat` to get a single array:

```js
const sample = [{
    "key": "sampleKey",
    "values": [{
      "key": "insidesampleKey",
      "value": 2
    }, {
      "key": "insideofinside",
      "value": 2
    }]
  },

  {
    "key": "sampleKey2",
    "values": [{
      "key": "insideSampleKey2",
      "value": 1
    }]
  },

  {
    "key": "samplkey3",
    "values": [{
      "key": "insideofsampleKey3",
      "value": 1
    }]
  }
];

console.log(sample.map(e => e.values.map(x => x.value)).flat(1));
```